Will the combustion chamber I have made work as intended

I am trying to make a fairly simple electric jet engine, this is the kinda the design I came up with. I just want to know if this is a sound design for my combustion chamber. Pretty new with jet engines and sheet metal working. So I am not really sure of the things that could possibly go wrong.
More context, Everything is stainless steel and I am using butane gas, and the the fuel line sticking through is also stainless steel. No spark plug, will ignite the thing by a lighter and the compression is done using a electric motor driven impeller, not shown here.

With an electric motor for your compressor... do you have a turbine section at all?  What benefit do you foresee by using butane instead of jet fuel?  Perhaps it would be better to understand existing jet engines more thoroughly, before working to design one from scratch.  There is 80+ years of experience with designing, building, and operating turbine engines out there, and you probably don't have enough time to make all of the mistakes yourself by reinventing things that have gone before.

@RalphJ Ah its just to get my hands dirty, see some fire shoot out of the contraption. Learn a couple of things before I try harder projects

Since this is effectively a butane stove 'work as intended' is likely - the primary safety risk is the butane cylinder - local and remote shut off valves, and a check valve so as cylinder pressure falls turbine cannot pump hot air INTO the cylinder making things explosive. Would expect it to set things on fire rather effectively. If objective is to learn things rather than make a flame thrower would suggest pressure and temperature monitors and a custom controller - design goal is to control fuel and turbine speed to manage temperature just below point exhaust goes engine rich.

Above comment only applies to design show - if it gains a compression turbine or other outlet restrictions to the area where fuel and high pressure air are mixing it moves from 'big camping stove' to 'pipe bomb' quite quickly, classically occurring during startup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine#Hard_starts

very insightful @GremlinWranger the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you so much, if you post that il accept it

On which side is the compressor and the turbine in your picture? Is that picture representing one can in a row or the whole chamber?
